# iSCSI New-IscsiVirtualDisk: Возникла непредвиденная ошибка (Hyper-V Windows Server 2019)

Tags: powershell, windows-server, hyper-v

Пытаюсь создать виртуальный диск iSCSI на виртуальной машине Hyper-V Windows Server 2019. Возникает непонятная ошибка. Перепробовал уже все, что нашел в интернете. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала, вместо скриншота следует скопировать **текст** ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Полный путь должен быть в кавычках

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вроде бы там и так пути в кавычках, хотя пробелов в них нет